# IOS NSDictionary Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdictionary

i have a NSDictonary looks like

```
{
    nowShowing =     (
        {
            programmeName = xx;
        },
        {
            programmeName = xx;
        },
        {
            programmeName = xx;
        }
    );
    programmeCategory =     (
        {
            imageUrl = "xx";
            programmeDescription = "xx";
            programmeName = xx;
        },
        {
            imageUrl = "xx";
            programmeDescription = "xx";
            programmeName = "xx";
        },
        {
            imageUrl = "xx";
            programmeDescription = "xx";
            programmeName = "xx";
        }
    );
    slideShowImages =     (
        {
            imageLink = "xx";
        },
        {
            imageLink = "xx";
        },
        {
            imageLink = "xx";
        },
        {
            imageLink = "xx";
        }
    );
}
```

I want to get these 3 variables (nowshowing , slideShowImages , programmecategory) separate inside my program is there a way can any body tell me how to do this, i am new to IOS development i dont know how to do this thank you

Comment: Did you try anything? What methods does `NSDictonary` have that might help you?

Comment: Nested dictionary structure. Retrieve value [[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"programmeCategory"] objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get it by using:

```
NSArray *nowShowing = [dictionary objectForKey:@"nowShowing"];

NSArray *programmeCategory = [dictionary objectForKey:@"programmeCategory"];

NSArray *slideShowImages = [dictionary objectForKey:@"slideShowImages"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You use this method:

```
[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Where "key" can be: "nowShowing", "programmeCategory" or "slideShowImages"

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *program = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"programmeCategory"];
```

Do the same for the other two. In this way you have an array with all the items of that object and you can refer to each like that:

```
[program objectAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access like this...........

```
NSArray *nowShowingArray,*programCategoryArray,*slideShowImagesArray; //Dont forget to alloc i havent done here
    nowShowingArray=[mainDict valueForKey:@"nowShowing"]; //these are array of dictionaries
    programCategoryArray=[mainDict valueForKey:@"programCategory"];
    slideShowImagesArray=[mainDict valueForKey:@"slideShowImages"];

    for (NSDictionary *object in nowShowingArray)
    {
        NSString *name=[object valueForKey:@"programmeName"];  //acess each like this
    }
    for (NSDictionary *object in programCategoryArray)
    {
        NSString *name,*imageUrl,*programDescription;
        imageUrl=[object valueForKey:@"imageUrl"];
        name=[object valueForKey:@"programName"];                         //acess each like this
        programDescription=[object valueForKey:@"programDescription"];
    }
    for (NSDictionary *object in slideShowImagesArray)
    {
        NSString *imageLink=[object valueForKey:@"imageLink"];
    }
```